# Domain Objects to map

Tags: java, groovy

We are building a micro-service REST api in groovy as part of a more complex application. This service would only just be a simple CRUD operations.

We are using groovy and on a GET we need to pull a record from the database ( mongodb ), and return the object after changing the format of some fields ( for backward compatibility ), something on these lines:

```
def object = collection.findOne(query)
object.field3 = object.field2.collect { [..]}
return object
```

I am not very experienced in groovy or java ( I worked more extensively on ruby/python/clojure ), but I would normally have a domain object:

```
class Foo {
  String _id
  String field1
  Array field2


  Map toMap() {  

    [field1: field1, field3: field2.collect {}, field2: field2]
  }
}
```

and then just go

```
foo = new Foo(objectMapFromDb)
foo.toMap()
```

and some of the benefits that I see by using this approach is that I can look at the domain object and have an idea of what the structure of the object in the database is, I can get some type safety if I want to but more importantly ( and that's what drove my decision ) is that the code for converting the map is encapsulated in a function and can be easily re used in other part of the project

A more senior developer questioned this approach mentioning YAGNI and stating that domain objects are too complex, and reverted back to just changing changing the map as above.

I am a bit puzzled, I tried to look around for information about avoiding domain objects but I can't find anything similar to that ( I have looked at the anaemic domain model, but this seems to take it to the extreme ). About yagni I don't feel it applies in this case.

I personally don't see anything terribly wrong with that, for a simple application seems like a fine solution, but the novelty of this approach really stimulate my curiosity.

Any thought on this? Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: If you have time, could you describe what the object looks like now vs what it is that you want?  It is a bit confusing in your post to figure out exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi hooknc , thanks for the reply, basically at the moment the domain object has been removed, we just convert the database record to a map "on flight", while I would have coded something like class Foo {} and passed around an instance of it and have the object to map conversion inside a toMap() function, hope it's clearer. cheers

Comment: Personally I don't see anything bad in adding `toMap` method to domain object. However I think that it's rather a serializer's job to provide all the fields matching previous version. You should change the API version and serve some fields with `v1` and other with `v2`.

Comment: Hi Opal, thanks for the reply, just to clarify, he doesn't just questions the toMap method, he thinks domain objects should not be used at all, thanks for the input on api versioning, I would have personally used it, but it was decided otherwise. cheers

Comment: i think the reasoning could be, that mongo provides you basically a map and the final result on your REST backend is also a map (even just a blob of it as json, xml, edn, ...). so why promote it to something more in between unless you need the typing.